# Matplotlib Deprecation Warning

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a histogram in a jupyter notebook using matplot, where I am trying to put 2 data sets on the same axis in order to compare them and I keep reciveing the deprecation warning and I cant seem to figure out why. What exactly is causing this problem?

```
ax3 = fig2.add_subplot(331)
ax3.set_xlabel("Danceability")
ax3.set_ylabel('Count')
ax3.set_title('Danceability Distribution')
pos_dance.hist(alpha = 0.5, bins = 30)
ax4 = fig2.add_subplot(331)
neg_dance.hist(alpha = 0.5, bins = 30)
```

Comment: Can you post the *actual* traceback?

Comment: Please consider adding a code sample, or revising the one you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. Good luck with your code!

Comment: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\deprecation.py:107: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Adding an axes using the same arguments as a previous axes currently reuses the earlier instance.  In a future version, a new instance will always be created and returned.  Meanwhile, this warning can be suppressed, and the future behavior ensured, by passing a unique label to each axes instance.

Comment: and thank you Masque for the advice sorry if i did it poorly.

Comment: Problem is `ax4 = fig2.add_subplot(331)` and `ax3 = fig2.add_subplot(331)` refer to the same axes. No need for that. Just plot everything to `ax3`.

Comment: that was it thanks joe, i feel pretty stupid now lol